# Invalid Date Format - Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

It might be a simple solution but I have some problems with it. I have JSON response with user data like name, address, and birthday. However, birthDay is empty and I cannot parse it.

Error (only those lines occure):

```
Exception has occurred.
FormatException (FormatException: Invalid date format
)
```

I'm using tryParse and DateFormatter with null check but it seems to not work as I expect. Below you'll find part of code and JSON response:

Part of response:

```
birthDay: "" // as you see it's empty
bioInfo: ""
badges: List(6 items)
agreement5: false
```

Part of Profile Entity:

```
class ProfileEntity {

final String birthDay;

ProfileEntity.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : birthDay = json['birthDay'],

}
```

Part of Profile Model:

```
class ProfileModel {

final DateTime birthDate;

ProfileModel({@required this.birthDate});

ProfileModel.fromEntities(
    ProfileEntity profileEntity,
  ) : birthDate = DateTime.tryParse(profileEntity.birthDay), //place where I'm getting an error - value is null in this case. 

//here I'm sending it to form field

Map<String, String> toFormFields() {
    return {
      'jform[birthDay]':
          birthDate != null ? DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(birthDate) : "", //null check
    }
  }

}
```

Do you have any idea how to get rid of this? (Error message do not provide any info despite what I paste above in error part)

Comment: Do you expect bdate to be empty and you want to ignore the error ? Can you show the json that you work with ?

Comment: I can ignore it at all, but in some cases it affects other parts od app - I don't know how and some widgets won't display until I do not fulfill this field (in up to 5% of users).

Now I'm wondering is not a good solution to add default date in case of null in response (in Entity part). Because at first it's trying to parse date from entity but it's null so error occurs. Then it's checking if it's null and replace it with an empty string. (sending to form fields)

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.tryParse` does not expect null value.

You can replace this with `DateTime.tryParse(profileEntity.birthDay ?? '')` which will return `null` instead of throwing exception.

For ref: [tryParse method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.2/dart-core/DateTime/tryParse.html)

Comment: I to doesn't work form me at all. I've edited: 

ProfileEntity.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : birthDay = json['birthDay'] == null ? "2000-01-01" :  json['birthDay'] 

and also add ?? '' in:

DateTime.tryParse(profileEntity.birthDay ?? '')

And still nothing.

Comment: I believe the ?? needs to be outside the parens, else it becomes part of the method's first argument. `DateTime.tryParse(profileEntity.birthDay) ?? ''`

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').parse(widget.initialDate);
```

remember you can change date format according to which you api sends date in my case 'dd-MM-yyy' in your case may be different format.